# Modify a 1D tensor on the basis of a condition

Tags: tensorflow

`I want to apply a condition to each element of a 1D tensor in tensorflow and hence modify the input tensor. For example, if the tensor is:

`y_true = tf.Variable([0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0])`,

I want to check whether each element is greater than `0.1` or not. If it is then that element becomes `1` else `0`. How could same be done in tensorflow?

What I have tried until now is, writing a python function and then using it in tensorflow using `py_func`, but it is not working. See below code -

```python
y_true = tf.Variable([0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    y = tf.py_func(round_with_threshold, [y_true], tf.float32)
    y.eval()

def round_with_threshold(arr):
    threshold = 0.1
    rounded_arr = np.zeros(arr.shape[0])
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        if arr[i]>=threshold:
            rounded_arr[i] = 1
        else:
            rounded_arr[i] = 0
    return rounded_arr
```

Is it possible to do this in `tensorflow` without writing any python function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```python
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = tf.Variable([0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0])
comp_op = tf.greater(y_true, 0.1) # returns boolean tensor
cast_op = tf.cast(comp_op, tf.int32) # casts boolean tensor into int32

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(cast_op))
```

prints: `[0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]`